# node-webkit and mysql queries

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, node-webkit

I'm a newbie with node-webkit. I'm trying to make a desktop app which connects to server, in my case, to WAMP local server and make queries with mysql module of node.js.

I have this (I'm spanish, so excuse if the name of the classes and variables are in my language):

```
var datos_utilizados = function(err, resultado){
    if(err){
        throw err;
    }
    var datos = $.parseJSON(resultado);
    var largo = datos.length;

    for(var i=0;i<largo;i++){
        var pelicula = "<div class='pelicula'><div class='etiqueta'>"+datos[i].nombreProducto+"<br><br>"+datos[i].descripcionProducto+"<br>Precio: "+datos[i].precioProducto+"</div></div>"
        $('#capsula').append(pelicula);
    }
}

consulta(datos_utilizados);

function consulta(callback){
    var mysql = require('../node_modules/mysql');
    var conexion = mysql.createConnection({
        host: 'localhost',
        user: 'root',
        password: '',
        database: 'prueba'  
    });

    conexion.connect();

    conexion.query('SELECT * FROM products', function(err, result){
        var json = '';      
        if(err){
            throw err;
        }else{
            json = JSON.stringify(result);
            console.log('It's ok'); 
            callback(null, json);   
        }

    });
    conexion.end(); 
}
```

It's just a little connection with local server and a simple query to show a movie list.

At first, everythig is okay, but I wanna insert a form into my html code and users can check out a full review of the movie or just look a movie list separate by genres. I think that needs get and post methods but I know node-webkit doesn't support php.
I was reading about Express module for Node.js, but I have wamp server.

Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You have this problem:

```
console.log('It's ok');
```

You close string with `It's`.

Try this:

```
console.log('It\'s ok');
```

or:

```
console.log("It's ok");
```